# getting "ClassNotFoundException" or "HTTP Status 404 – Not Found" when running jsp or servlet

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets

//index.jsp file

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>

    <form action="IndexServlet" >
        <input type="text" name="username">
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
    
</body>
</html>
```

//servlet file

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import jakarta.servlet.ServletException;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class Index extends HttpServlet{

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {


        PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();
        out.println("Hi There!");
    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tIjpg.png)

I want to print "Hi There!" when hitting submit from jsp file. but when I do I either get a 404 or 500 error

//////////////////////////

HTTP Status 404 – Not Found
Type Status Report

Description The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.

Apache Tomcat/10.0.27

//////////////////////////

```
HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error
Type Exception Report

Message Error instantiating servlet class [com.bootcamp.IndexServlet]

Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Exception

jakarta.servlet.ServletException: Error instantiating servlet class [com.bootcamp.IndexServlet]
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:690)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:356)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:870)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1762)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Root Cause

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.bootcamp.IndexServlet
```

Comment: I mean… the servlet has no “package”, it isn’t named what the error message can’t find, and we can’t see how you’re attempting to map the servlet.

Comment: it is inside the "Exercise". It's what's showed when I created a new package

Comment: I'm typing a username as an input on jsp, and after I clicked submit, I want to print "Hi There!"

Comment: you should insert `@WebServlet(value = "/index")` before the class declaration,
and in your form it should be `action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/index"`

Comment: I've also done that but still got error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I think a .class file is missing. I created a new project where the class file is visible and it worked

not sure how it's working. lol

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l8ta9.png)

I've read about the articles here:

[Tomcat: the origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47945008/tomcat-the-origin-server-did-not-find-a-current-representation-for-the-target-r)

[Unable to instantiate a servlet, getting class not found exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40752465/unable-to-instantiate-a-servlet-getting-class-not-found-exception)

[Eclipse doesn't compile java files into classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18010749/eclipse-doesnt-compile-java-files-into-classes)